# Connection refused to Flask WSGI application on Apache2

Tags: apache2, flask, wsgi

I am attempting to get a Flask API running on Apache2 Server but I am getting a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Since I am running the flask API on another server I am using a Proxy Reverse on my main apache server in the following manner:

```
Listen 5001
<VirtualHost *:5001>
        ServerAdmin myapiserver@mydomain.com
        ServerName myapiserver.io
        SSLEngine on
        SSLOptions +ExportCertData
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/myapiserver/STAR_myapiserver_io.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/myapiserver/myapiserver.io.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/myapiserver/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
        SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyPass / https://10.0.10.242:5001/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://10.0.10.242:5001/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

My `myapiserver` configuration:

```
Listen 5001
<VirtualHost *:5001>
     ServerName myapiserver.io
     SSLEngine on
     SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/myapiserver/STAR_myapiserver_io.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/myapiserver/myapiserver.io.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/myapiserver/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
     WSGIDaemonProcess restapi user=www-data group=www-data threads=4 python-path=/applications/restapi/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages
     WSGIProcessGroup restapi
     WSGIScriptAlias / /applications/restapi/restapi.wsgi
     WSGIPassAuthorization On
     <Directory /applications/restapi>
        <Files restapi.wsgi>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Files>
     </Directory>
     <Directory /applications/restapi/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog /applications/logs/restapi.error.log
     LogLevel warn
     CustomLog /applications/logs/restapi.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have verified the firewall rules and the request is `https://myapiserver.io:5001`

The python code is launched like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

I cannot understand why it is not connecting and I have run out of options to try.  Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: And you checked that Apache is running and isn't failing to start?

Comment: I figured the previous comment I made was misleading.  I verified the server is up and running.  No logs or errors; however, it still will not connect.  Sorry for any confusion.